# Syntax error :Invalid or unexpected token at htmlbuttonelement

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0CrQ.jpg)
Making a simple calculator but when pressing = button on calculator, the if condition which is evaluating the string in the string variable is throwing a syntax error: invalid or unexpected token at htmlbuttonelement

Error in line
String=eval(string)

Try gpt and Google also

Comment: You should check to see what `string` contains if evaling it throws an error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.